# Just upgraded to a newer version of Photoshop, how do I get Lightroom to recognize it?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, lightroom-4, photoshop-cs5

I had PS5.1 when I installed LR4 and now I have CS6, but LR4 still opens everything in CS5.1. How do I make it open everything in CS6?

Comment: Why not just uninstall CS5.1? Any particular reason why you would want to revert to the old version?

Comment: I have licenses for CS5.1 and LR4 under the old licensing model whereas I acquired CS6 under the new CC subscription model. Should I ever cancel my CC membership I would like the ability to revert back to LR4/CS5.1 like I had it yesterday before I purchased CC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming Windows OS, if you are comfortable editing your registry:

- open registry (using regedit command)
- navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
- look for a key called "Photoshop.exe"
- if it is there, it will probably contain a path to CS5.  Edit the entry and paste in the path to your CS6 executable
- if it is not there, add it using the information in the following

http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/edit-photoshop-command-missing-photoshop.html

Alternately, uninstall CS5 and then reinstall LR4 and it will pick up CS6.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you to MikeW. I used your solution and it worked a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently one solution is to have your computer lockup and have to hard reset causing LR4 to see CS6 upon startup. I'll leave this open for a more solid answer, preferably one that includes how to revert, or select, the version (or install) of PS that should be used in case I want to go back to an old version at some time.

Comment: Had you rebooted your computer?  Most likely the file association wasn't changed until reboot.  I imagine it just uses whatever has the association registered in Windows, though that is a bit of a guess.

Comment: I'm on a Mac, but my guess is that LR checks for PS on startup and uses the latest one it finds. Because LR was open when I installed CS6 it probably didn't find it until I reopened LR because of the crash.

Comment: even on Mac, it's probably still done off file association, though they may look for installed versions of Photoshop.  In general, file associations would probably be easier though as the OS already provides it and it includes the path to the executable.